# Types of parameters when making function use callback function other than input parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to use a generic function that takes a callback function. But the argument to the callback function will be different for each type of function. I have defined the following but ts still does not understand and i got the error

```
Argument of type '({ name1 }: { name1: string; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CBTest'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'obj' are incompatible.
    Type 'Param1 | Param2' is not assignable to type '{ name1: string; }'.
      Property 'name1' is missing in type 'Param2' but required in type '{ name1: string; }'.
```

Here is my example, and i created one on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=31&pln=40&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBOCiAPADiATlAjDAvDAFAN4xgCGAtgKbYC+AXDMWVZg9GgJZgDmNAlDAYA3EBwAmuAHyMAUDHkxQkEABtKAOhUhu+ZtT4yaMmUuhwwSVBgBMuAkwqVb9RiUfW2UTj36CR4qVkFRXAIVQ0tHT1rAyMZKABPZEoYAAVSNApsPEI5BT1WGHYubkNjROS0jIpbHLz5aM9vUriAelaYCpSAFUpoAB5uzAAaGG7pOvbgxQAjBnwQGYArBm6BHGl-MRkp4NIZ4AB+VcwdjriumABhACFeszwF5YZ0zPJsAB8qt9t1zdFtmdOkken0oINMBNZLsFMA5gRFitvlkYF9XjU-jAtkC9gdjmNTlM4qZYFAwZZ0LBHnCGLd7lBRvtgE0SgJArlghwAGYEJm4HB4ADkwFIEGogoEcKIbhYDAARAU5TB+PUYJQVGLZtLGjAFe4lSq2h0SZ1yShKXZpUzRnDlaswf1ijxRuj3qjkeRrJI2RtoR1OTz8HyBUKRWLMBKtQ5ZbrFcqDDD5OrNVLo055dEDQnzsZ4marFAFhZzRgRrqw9Q5QYydAKRgi3WoNZRnKK9Yq0Ca1BG1aDvK23KbfCECWm-HjFMuz3iEz+6LK0OGCOC7Rs6ba6Pe8zy-P24vzI3nHwgA)

```
const onExport1 = ({ name1 }: { name1: string}) : void => {
    console.log(name1)
}

const onExport2 = ({ name2 }: { name2: string}) :void => {
    console.log(name2)
}

type Param1 = {
    name1: string
}

type Param2 = {
    name2: string
}

type CBTest = (obj: Param1 | Param2 ) => void

const testExport = (cb: CBTest, abc: string)  => {
    if (abc === 'case1') cb({ name1: "name1" })
    else cb({ name2: "name2" })
}

testExport(onExport1, "case1")
testExport(onExport2, "case2")
```

Comment: It looks like you want the `cb` and `abc` parameters of `testExport` to be of a [destructured discriminated union type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5Ak2N).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you that's exactly what I wanted, this is quite new to me, can you explain more

Comment: No, please do not edit your question with an answer; if you want to self-answer you should post it as an answer below.  But since I'm willing to answer and explain it you should probably just let me do it.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry about that, i have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CBTest` type accepts a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Param1` and `Param2` inputs, meaning that a function of that type accepts any input of either `Param1` or `Param2`... meaning it needs to handle *both* possibilities.  Your `onExport1` and `onExport2` functions don't behave like that, though.  Instead of `(obj: Param1 | Param2) => void`, you probably should say `((obj: Param1) => void) | ((obj: Param2) => void)`, so that a `CBTest` *either* accepts a `Param1`, *or* it accepts a `Param2`, but it's not required to accept both.  This will at least allow you to make calls:

```
type CBTest = typeof onExport1 | typeof onExport2;
const testExport = (cb: CBTest, abc: string) => { ⋯ }
testExport(onExport1, "case1"); // okay
testExport(onExport2, "case2"); // okay
```

But even so, your call signature for `testExport()` doesn't describe any particular relationship between the `cb` and the `abc` inputs.  You allow `abc` to be any `string` whatsoever (when it should probably only be `"case1"` or `"case2"`, at least for the example), and `cb` is a function of (the revised) `CBTest` type which either accepts a `Param1` or accepts a `Param2`.  But nothing about the call signature connects the two, so the implementation will fail:

```
type CBTest = typeof onExport1 | typeof onExport2;
const testExport = (cb: CBTest, abc: string) => {
    if (abc === 'case1')
        cb({ name1: "name1" }); // error
    else
        cb({ name2: "name2" }); // error
}
```

And nothing will stop bad calls from being made:

```
testExport(onExport1, "case2"); // okay?
testExport(onExport2, "case1"); // okay?
testExport(onExport1, "oops"); // okay?!
```

---

The necessary fix is to relate the `abc` input to the `cb` input, by making the parameter list for `testExport` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types). Like this:

```
type TestExport = (...args: 
     [cb: (x: Param1) => void, abc: "case1"] | 
     [cb: (x: Param2) => void, abc: "case2"]
) => void
declare const testExport: TestExport;
```

Here the `testExport` function is of type `TestExport`, which accepts *either* a `cb`/`abc` pair appropriate for case 1, *or* a `cb`/`abc` pair appropriate for case 2.  The `abc` input is a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), so it can be used as a *discriminant property* to distinguish between cases.

With that call signature, now only acceptable calls are accepted:

```
testExport(onExport1, "case1"); // okay
testExport(onExport2, "case2"); // okay
testExport(onExport1, "case2"); // error
testExport(onExport2, "case1"); // error
testExport(onExport1, "oops"); // error
```

Furthermore, you can now implement the function and it will type check:

```
const testExport: TestExport = (cb, abc) => {
    if (abc === 'case1')
        cb({ name1: "name1" }); // okay
    else
        cb({ name2: "name2" }); // okay
}
```

That's because `cb` and `abc` are inferred by the `TestExport` annotation to be of a [*destructured* discriminated union type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).  So the compiler will remember the relationship between `abc` and `cb`, and checking `abc` will be used to narrow the type of `cb`.

---

That's essentially the answer to the question.  Still, it might be a bit tedious to have to write out the `TestExport` type manually, especially if you have more than two cases.  To deal with that we can write a helper interface to match the cases, and then a utility type to generate `TestExport` from it:

```
interface ExportCaseMap {
    case1: Param1,
    case2: Param2,
    // add more cases here if needed
}

type TestExportParams = { [K in keyof ExportCaseMap]:
    [cb: (x: ExportCaseMap[K]) => void, abc: K]
}[keyof ExportCaseMap];
/* type TestExportParams = 
     [cb: (x: Param1) => void, abc: "case1"] | 
     [cb: (x: Param2) => void, abc: "case2"] 
*/

type TestExport = (...args: TestExportParams) => void;
```

So `ExportCaseMap` is the type you manually maintain.  And the `TestExportParams` type is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) that computes the `cb`/`abc` pair for each entry in `ExportCaseMap`. And finally `TestExport` is the function type you need.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-wAulAOhbrTMoHaHe5ncl1G7lqtPXcIG5vj7YRHXVB1SCHEFgJ1KnrQsJSLr9TnxNN3asI3sXscQ2cLtcvQ8nsjDm8otIvpjO9igUj4YjWwd2x9pD4ft5e4N8sA8yWxCEWiIlt8m-9caS2ABrOAgRxzgvABdNQ9uFdNxMb8Hb3f7ijzxdhVDn+OX4Gkgkw2f3w-Hktnn412+K8IShL8DyXP9D2fH42FGMhgPffEwKJNVrwQKAFWpdhKSMLRWTgFQWXZfQ2GQMAqBMDD2HIylZyOHNOQwrCmBoWcEDqOAWGgEsinjABZOAwBwJE1zDNAFlE19xLcYkCmcYtD3kFBxiwXBLQAaSOOktwgBUGl4gShJ9YgkSDW17SgQz7kEsBNJ9VMowrNYoA05MGEtXT9Ksw8+Js4zBg1LUFIgsJlOQVSoEDG0Q0s8KnTSV1nLjb0k39KLkXM2KZMczRksA180qYDN5OgRSl0NY0EFNItQuEcKyFyjRBiAA)